# Is it possible to use SQL Azure Reporting with a filtered SQL Azure Federation database?

Tags: reporting-services, azure-sql-database, federation

Is it possible to use SQL Azure Reporting Services with a SQL Azure database using Federation, with tables federated by tenant ID, and the requirement that all access to the database is done through a connection filtered by the federation key, i.e., filtered by tenant?

Merely connecting to a specific federation member database as suggested in [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/9c00ca77-9328-401a-86c7-cba99addd886/) wouldn't be enough, because one tenant must not be able to view another tenant's data. The connection must be filtered by SQL Azure Federations through the use of the "FILTERING=ON" condition.

Is there any way to have SQL Azure Reporting Services execute the necessary USE FEDERATION command to have the connection filtered by the federation key?

Or alternatively, to have Reporting Services access data in any other way (like an OData web service) that might be filtered?

The desired result is that each tenant can run a report and only see their own data.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure Reporting Services is not federation aware (as of the current version), so your best choice is to write a service and have SARS use that service as the data source.

Comment: That would probably be enough, but is it possible? [Guidelines and Limitations for SQL Azure Reporting Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg430132.aspx) seems to imply that only SQL Azure datasources are supported.